# How can i add marker on open street map without mentioning lat long

Tags: openstreetmap, marker

The codes i have displays the map and the marker pops up on only those areas for which the lat long are mentioned in the code but for my web application I want the user to touch on any area and a marker is displayed with a pop up showing the lat long and other attributes of the place

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is your question about a specific library? Both Leaflet and OpenLayers allow to return coordinates for onClick events.

Comment: This is my first hand experience with coding and web application development....so far i have displayed a simple open street map using leaflet. I have seen a few tutorials but could not understand the code. It would be great if I could get a simple code  for adding marker on the map with a pop up.message for understanding purpose .

Comment: For Leaflet check https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/210102/23837.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Inline Map</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body background="G:\Intership\sfedit.jpeg" style="width:100%">


<p style="text-align:centre;">Learn for free</p>
    <!-- To display the map -->
        <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- Map Code -->   
            <script>
    // Create variable to hold map element, give initial settings to map
        var map = L.map('map',{ center: [18.5214280, 73.8544541], zoom: 14});

        // Add OpenStreetMap tile layer to map element
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>' }).addTo(map);

       // Create an Empty Popup
        var popup = L.popup();

        // Write function to set Properties of the Popup
        function onMapClick(e) {
            popup
                .setLatLng(e.latlng)
                .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
                .openOn(map);
        }

        // Listen for a click event on the Map element
        map.on('click', onMapClick);
                  fetch('https://cdn.glitch.com/3b46ae34-c2e2-48fe-b99c-5bb9412d0e1a%2Fpmpml_geojson_busstop.geojson?v=1589713237973')
                .then(function (response){
                return response.json();
                })
                .then(function(data){
                L.geoJson(data,{
                onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                    layer.bindPopup("bus stop name:"+feature.properties['stop_name']+ "<br>stop code:"+feature.properties['stop_code']+ "<br>Latitude:"+feature.properties['stop_lat']+ "<br>Longitude:"+feature.properties['stop_lon']);
                }
                }).addTo(map);
                });

                fetch('https://cdn.glitch.com/3b46ae34-c2e2-48fe-b99c-5bb9412d0e1a%2FPune_streetfile.geojson?v=1589720389890')
                .then(function (response){
                return response.json();
                })
                .then(function(data){
                L.geoJSON(data).addTo(map);
                });


            </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have used fetch function to display my geojson data on the map and it works successfully but the only problem is that my map takes time to load.

Answer (score 0):

`//fetching geojson data from given URL 
                  fetch( "https://cdn.glitch.com/3b46ae34-c2e2-48fe-b99c-5bb9412d0e1a%2Fpmpml_surgeon_busstop.geojson?v=1589713237973"
                  )
                    .then(function(response) {
                      return response.json();
                    })
                    .then(function(data) {
                      //adding code for cluster
                      var clusters = L.markerClusterGroup();
                      var incidents = L.geoJson(data, {
                        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
                          var marker = L.marker(latlng);
                          marker.bindPopup(
                            "bus stop name:" +
                              feature.properties["stop_name"] +
                              "
stop code:" +
                              feature.properties["stop_code"] +
                              "
Latitude:" +
                              feature.properties["stop_lat"] +
                              "
Longitude:" +
                              feature.properties["stop_lon"]  );
                          return marker;
                        },
                        onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
                          layer.addTo(clusters);
                        }
                      });
                      map.addLayer(clusters);
                    });

``

Comment: This code does not seem to work. I want to create cluster for my marker using marker cluster plugin. I went through all the possible solution but nothing seems to happen. Map data is getting displayed but when i add marker cluster me data disappears